# Why are these two JS functions different?

Tags: javascript

When `lsEstimator` is an array with 2 elements, this function returns `true`:

```
function got_estimators() {
  var retval = 
   (typeof lsEstimator != 'undefined' &&
    lsEstimator != null &&
   lsEstimator.length > 0);
  return retval;
}
```

but this function doesn't (it returns `undefined`, I think, in Chrome and FF):

```
function got_estimators() {
   return 
      (typeof lsEstimator != 'undefined' &&
      lsEstimator != null &&
      lsEstimator.length > 0);
}
```

Why?

Comment: @FelixKling you should write an answer since it is the proper one.

Comment: Wow. 1 minute is pretty good. So what does the second function actually do?

Comment: Automatic semicolon insertion is the root of all evil :-(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because of the line break after `return` in the second example. The code is evaluated as:

```
function got_estimators() {
   return; // <-- bare return statement always results in `undefined`.
   (typeof lsEstimator != 'undefined' &&
    lsEstimator != null &&
    lsEstimator.length > 0);
}
```

JavaScript is not even evaluating the logical operators.

Why does this happen? Because JavaScript has *automatic semicolon insertion*, i.e. it tries to insert semicolons "where it makes sense" ([more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)).

Put the `return` keyword and the return value in the same line:

```
return (typeof lsEstimator != 'undefined' &&
  lsEstimator != null &&
  lsEstimator.length > 0);
```

Comment: The one and only reason for putting curly braces on the statement line !

Comment: That's pretty amazing. Just found Crockford's JavaScript 'awful parts' at http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/awful-parts.html, and this comes in at No. 3.